Regions whose area cannot be measure in the sense of Riemann
Consider a region $D$ of the plane. Usually, its area is defined as
$$
\iint_D 1
$$
Would it be possible that this integral does not exists, and thus $D$ has a non-measurable area?

Sure. There is a notion of a non-measurable set (e.g. the Vitali set) and it's not hard to generalize this to arbitrary dimensions (e.g. here). But this might be a bit overkill if you're focusing on the Riemann case, since measurability of sets is generally not discussed without discussing the (more general) Lebesgue integral.

It would be good to edit the question to include the definition of region. To some authors this means a connected open set; to others, maybe it means a subset, or the closure of a bounded, connected open set with piecewise continuously-differentiable boundary, or something else.

For the Riemann integral, the integral exists (in the proper sense) if and only if $D$ is a bounded set such that the boundary has measure-zero.
And it is very easy to come up with examples of sets, even countable ones, violating this condition, for example $\Bbb{Q}^n\cap [0,1]^n$.
